# Gradle eclipse dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I need to use eclipse on a project and gradle for my testing. orginally my testing was done with testng and maven. I first did the gradle init and it all seems to work fine. I normally use intellij and got no problem running my project. But when I import my project in eclipse it keeps saying "the import .... could not be resolved" on every import I do.

this is my build.gradle. Keep in mind I only did the gradle init so if I'm doing something wrong at this point I just don't know

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

group = 'be.test'
version = '1.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = """"""

repositories {

     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version:'2.52.0'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version:'1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.velocity', name: 'velocity', version:'1.7'
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version:'4.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'3.8.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version:'6.9.4'
}
```

Is it a gradle problem, or am I just missing something in eclipse what is automatically done in intellij?

Comment: You should be using Buildship to configure the project in Eclipse, not `gradle eclipse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out after looking closer into the tasks of gradle you can do

```
gradle cleanEclipse
```

and after that

```
gradle eclipse
```

After that I reloaded the project and all was fine